# Adding multiple terms to the For Statement

Tags: java

My question is why output is 0 - 4? But not 0 - 9?

```
int x = 0;
for (long y = 0, z = 4; x < 5 && y < 10; x++, y++) {
   System.out.print(y + " ");
}
```

also next code doesn't compile?

```
int x = 0;
for (long y = 0, x = 4; x < 5 && y < 10; x++, y++) {
   System.out.print(x + " ");
}
```

Could you explain why?

Comment: Because `x` cannot exceed `4`; i.e. `x < 5`

Comment: `x<5` gives you that since `&&` requires both sides to be true.

Comment: but I am printing y and not x

Comment: Check the parenthesis around the condition.

Comment: By the way, just because you can define multiple variables in a for statement, doesn't mean you should.  Try to make your code easy for people to understand.

Answer (score 2):

```
int x = 0;
for (long y = 0, z = 4; x < 5 && y < 10; x++, y++) {
    System.out.print(y + " ");
}
```

The above prints 0 to 4 since `x < 5 && y < 10` can only be true when both inequalities are true.  So as soon as `x == 5`, the loop exits.

```
int x = 0;      
for (long y = 0, x = 4; x < 5 && y < 10; x++, y++) {
        System.out.print(x + " ");
}
```

The above doesn't compile because you have already defined `x` as an `int`.  The first part of the loop tries to redefine it as a `long`

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = 0;
for (long y = 0, z = 4; x < 5 && y < 10; x++, y++) {
   System.out.print(y + " ");
}
```

The condition is not true when x == 5, x <5 && y <10, your condition is that x is less than 5, and y is less than 10, so the condition is not true when x == 5, if you change the condition to || will output 0-9

```
int x = 0;
for (long y = 0, x = 4; x < 5 && y < 10; x++, y++) {
   System.out.print(x + " ");
}
```

This does not compile because the x value has been defined, regardless of the type.The reason for this kind of error is because Java itself is not allowed, "Java designers think that doing so will cause program confusion"